# How to reconnect to database server on personal PC?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, database-server

I am just starting to learn SQL.  I downloaded MySQL and created a server with it on my PC.  I was able to connect to the server and start trying SQL commands.  Now its a couple days later, when I open MySQL workbench and try to connect to the server I get this error:
"Cannot Connect to Database Server"  then below it says
"Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306:
Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' reported error:
Authentication requires secure connection. "

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried steps in official documentation, about this error ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html